# Solving Roman numerals with Julia's metaprogramming

Tags: julia, metaprogramming

I solved the exercise with regular Julia code, wasn't too hard:

```
function to_roman(number::Int64)
    0 < number < 4000 || error("not in range")

    parts = Char[]
    while number > 0
        if number >= 1000
            push!(parts, 'M')
            number -= 1000
        elseif number >= 500
            push!(parts, 'D')
            number -= 500
        # ...
            number -= 10
        elseif number >= 5
            push!(parts, 'V')
            number -= 5
        elseif number >= 1
            push!(parts, 'I')
            number -= 1
        end
    end
    join(parts)
end
```

This only solves naïve numerals, but keeps the example shorter. Now me being me, I'm appalled by the redundancy in this. So I made iteration 2:

```
const values = Dict(
    'M' => 1000,
    'C' => 100,
    'X' => 10,
    'I' => 1,
    'D' => 500,
    'L' => 50,
    'V' => 5,
)
Base.:+(number::Integer, c::Char) = number + values[c]
Base.:-(number::Integer, c::Char) = number - values[c]

function to_roman(number::Int64)
    0 < number < 4000 || error("must be between 1 and 3999 inclusive")

    parts = Char[]
    while number > 0
        for digit in "MDCLXVI"
            if number >= values[digit]
                push!(parts, digit)
                number -= digit
                break
            end
        end
    end
    join(parts)
end
```

That also does it, but got me thinking. Couldn't I create the redundant `if`s above with metaprogramming? That's something I wanted to learn about anyway and this seems like a not too hard place to wet my feet. But it's also not overly simple, like an `unless`.

*I'm aware that this is not what you use metaprogramming for. It is about the learning experience. Just as nobody needs to compute Fibonacci, but still we all learn to code it in FP.*

But I can't even get close:

```
macro gen(number)
    code = quote
        parts = Char[]
        while $(esc(number)) > 0
        end
    end
    for (i,c) in enumerate("MDCLXVI")
        exp = :(
            if $(esc(number)) >= $(values[c])
                push!(parts, $c)
                $(esc(number)) -= $(values[c])
            end
        )
        if i > 1
            exp.head = :elseif
        end
        # This is not correct anymore because I introduced the while.
        push!(code.args, exp)
    end
    push!(code.args, :(return parts))
    dump(code)
    return code
end

function test(number)
    @gen number
end

test(1111)
```

This is the best I could do, but then I noticed I need to have the `while` around (so this code doesn't work). Now I don't even know which `.args` to append to, because also there are several `LineNumberNode` nodes in there that shift the important ones around.

I got the feeling, I'm not approaching this from the right angle / am using the right tools.

So the overall question would be “How can I use metaprogramming to abstract away the `if` chain and redundancy of the primitive example in spirit of the second example?”

Comment: You can call `to_roman` from a macro. However, meta-programming is an advanced feature and should not be used for tasks like this. From the post I assume you are now learning Julia and I would advise against starting your learning from programming macros. Basically, a typical Julia user never needs to write macros on his own. If you have however a question on your macros please make it into MRE that focuses on just one issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This is implemented here: https://github.com/anthonyclays/RomanNumerals.jl/blob/12c81f7ad3797ae783607dd3a624963a9200ba53/src/types.jl#L18

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel No, I've been doing quite a bit of Julia already, but never MP. And of course I know the whole fine print about it, which is why I gave the whole backstory and not a MRE. Because with only an MRE, you'll just get the “don't use it in this case” answers.

Don't agree with the example code though. It uses macros, but not to reduce the `if` cascade.

Comment: I would still prefer question with a single or nested `if` and how to do that as macro, without the "roman letters" part. In this example currently IHMO it is not clear what question you ask about macros. I run ` @macroexpand @generate_ifs 55` with your current answer and still do not know what you would like to know. And the code generated is also not in the spirit of why we use meta-programming. I would definitely prefer here a minimalistic "hello world" example as the question. But of course this is just a humble advise on how to attract useful answers.

Comment: Added to the question, I hope that clarifies.

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel re: "not in the spirit of why we use metaprogramming", is there a good guide somewhere for when to use metaprogramming in Julia? The manual gives a similar vague warning about this being an "advanced feature". It would be nice to have some examples for "intended" use-cases, highlighting any idiosyncracies of the Julia mp implementation compared to others.

Answer (score 0):

Take a break and suddenly, stuff works.

My problem was that I was thinking kind of a top-down approach with manually mutating the `.args` of an `Expr` and counting which indices I need from examples and such… Way too manual and complicated.

Coming back to it, I realized I need to go bottom up, starting with the `I` case as a complete if and then always interpolating what I have so far in the newer, bigger `if`s `else`.

In the end, package it all up in a `while` and take care of the array, done.

```
macro generate_ifs(number)
    values = Dict(
        'M' => 1000,
        'C' => 100,
        'X' => 10,
        'I' => 1,
        'D' => 500,
        'L' => 50,
        'V' => 5,
    )
    code = :()
    for c in "IVXLCDM"
        code = :(
            if $(esc(number)) >= $(values[c])
                push!(parts, $c)
                $(esc(number)) -= $(values[c])
            else
                $code
            end
        )
    end
    return quote
        parts = Char[]
        while $(esc(number)) > 0
            $code
        end
        return join(parts)
    end
end

function to_roman(number::Int64)
    0 < number < 4000 || error("must be between 1 and 3999 inclusive")
    @generate_ifs number
end
```

---

As suggested in the comments, one can do away with the outer `while` by replaceing the `if`s:

```
macro generate_ifs(number)
    values = Dict(
        'M' => 1000,
        'C' => 100,
        'X' => 10,
        'I' => 1,
        'D' => 500,
        'L' => 50,
        'V' => 5,
    )
    code = :()
    for c in "IVXLCDM"
        code = quote
            while $(esc(number)) >= $(values[c])
                push!(parts, $c)
                $(esc(number)) -= $(values[c])
            end
            $code
        end
    end
    return quote
        parts = Char[]
        $code
        return join(parts)
    end
end
```

---

Anyway, that's the solution I came up with, I was also able to solve the proper numerals.

I'm still interested in comments and ideas.

Comment: If the macro already uses `while`, why unroll the `if`s instead of looping over possible roman letters? (saving a bit of code in the output of the macro)

Comment: You're right, that wouldn't be needed in the presented case. I _think_ I need it for the more complex case that also cares about 4s and 9s correctly.

Comment: I was not able to convert the `if`s to `while`s in the general case, because they're interleaved. But I'll update my answer for the naïve case.

Answer (score 0):

The following implementation might be helpful:

```
const roman_vals = [1000,500,100,50,10,5,1]
const roman_lets = collect("MDCLXVI")
function roman(V)
    r = Char[]
    for (z,c) in zip(roman_lets,roman_vals)
        while c < 2*V
            if c > V
                j = findlast(>=(c-V), roman_vals)
                c <= 2*roman_vals[j] && break
                push!(r, roman_lets[j])
                V += roman_vals[j]
            end
            push!(r, z)
            V -= c
        end
    end
    join(r)
end
```

Giving:

```
julia> roman(19)
"XIX"

julia> roman(1890)
"MDCCCXC"
```